# Why does the Android review process think I'm accessing my user's location?

Tags: android, flutter

```
SPLIT_BUNDLE 5: Policy Declaration - Data Safety Section: Location Data Type - Precise Location
```

I've got a small app I'm trying to get into Open Testing and I keep getting pinged by the Data Safety requirements. I've been adding more and more to it, mostly based on the information our servers send to the app, not the other way around.

All the app ever asks for is the user's email address, not even a password BUT I do have Sentry loaded to give me crash reports - primarily on the json feeds. When I look at Sentry's reports I can't see location so maybe it's not that?

The app is flutter, here's the pubspec.yaml dependencies

```
    dependencies:
      flutter:
        sdk: flutter
      fvm: ^2.4.1
      cupertino_icons: ^1.0.5
      dio: ^5.2.1+1
      intl: ^0.18.1
      flutter_html: ^3.0.0-alpha.6  #^2.2.1 #
      shared_preferences: ^2.2.0
      json_theme: ^6.0.0
      cached_network_image: ^3.2.1
      meta: ^1.7.0
      maps_launcher: ^2.0.1
      fluttertoast: ^8.2.2
      barcode_widget: ^2.0.4
      url_launcher: ^6.1.11
      sentry_flutter: ^7.7.0
```

Is there anything I can take out, substitute, whatever. I really don't want to tell my users I'm capturing their location when I'm not.

I've looked through the Sentry logs and their documentation but can't see anything there. I'm not sure where else to look.

Comment: Most likely because your app contains in AndroidManifest.xml that it want's to access location. At least one of the used libraries will place that permission request there. That is the problem of non-native programming languages like flutter.

Comment: @Robert - thanks for the pointer, I'll go through the manifests and see what's there

Comment: Have a look also at Merged Manifests, these manifests are created during compilation and sometimes some pubs add the location to the manifest when building